# Why "year" isn't in plural in this phrase?

Tags: adjectives, singular-vs-plural, compounds

"This is a difficult problem for a fifteen-year-old boy."

My guess is that "fifteen-year-old" forms an adjective, but I'm not really sure.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentence

> **fifteen-year-old** boy

is used as an adjective for boy

In the case of

> He is a **fifteen-year-old**.

it is used as a compound noun.

in contrast to

> He is fifteen **years** old

to say how many years he has been alive.

Comment: Thank you very much. You make me feel I'm on the right track.

Comment: It's a twelve-*inch*-long ruler.  It's a seven-*day* course of antibiotic.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.grammar.cl/english/compound-adjectives.htm
Compound adjectives are written with hypen, and nouns after numbers don't get a plural-s.